# Upgrade Visual Studio 2008 to SP1 to install SQL Server 2008 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2008, ssms

Why do I need to to upgrade my Visual Studio 2008 to SP1 in order to install SQL Server 2008 Management Studio if I already have Microsoft Visual Studio 2010? How to avoid not to upgrade anymore my Visual Studio 2008 to SP1 to successfully install SQL Server 2008 Management Studio?

Comment: What's the reason not to upgrade to VS 2008SP1, unless it's some sort of company policy issue?  I can't think of a good reason not to upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Visual Studio 2008 and one or more 2008 Express Editions, you must upgrade all of them to SP1.